# How to add Subpartition for existing table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, partition

I wanted to add subpartition for '`US`' market in `SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE` for exisitng `INT_TMP` table. So the subpartition should be like: `SUBPARTITION "SP_US" VALUES ( 'US' )` in `SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE` for exisitng `INT_TMP` table.

Below is my Create table statment:

```
CREATE TABLE INT_TMP
   (LOAD_ID NUMBER 
, SYS_DB_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, ENTITY_ID NUMBER 
, CHK_DATE DATE 
, VALUE NUMBER 
, NBR_CHECK VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MONTH_ID NUMBER
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA_INT_TCA_EDW" 
  PARTITION BY LIST ("MONTH_ID") 
  SUBPARTITION BY LIST ("SYS_DB_NAME") 
  SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE ( 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_SO" VALUES ( 'SO' ), 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_UK" VALUES ( 'UK' ), 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_OTHERS" VALUES ( DEFAULT ) ) 
 ( 
 PARTITION P_201801  VALUES (201801) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW , 
 PARTITION P_201802  VALUES (201802) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW , 
 PARTITION P_201803  VALUES (201803) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW , 
 PARTITION P_201804  VALUES (201804) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW , 
 PARTITION P_201805  VALUES (201805) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW , 
 PARTITION P_201806  VALUES (201806) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE DATA_INT_TCA_EDW ) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the subpartition template you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE INT_TMP
SET SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE ( 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_SO" VALUES ( 'SO' ), 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_UK" VALUES ( 'UK' ), 
    SUBPARTITION "SP_US" VALUES ( 'US' ),
    SUBPARTITION "SP_OTHERS" VALUES ( DEFAULT ) )
/

Table INT_TMP altered.
```

But you probably want to (also) split the existing default subpartitions:

```
ALTER TABLE INT_TMP
SPLIT SUBPARTITION "P_201801_SP_OTHERS"
VALUES ('US') INTO (SUBPARTITION "P_201801_SP_US", SUBPARTITION "P_201801_SP_OTHERS")
PARALLEL
/

Table INT_TMP altered.

ALTER TABLE INT_TMP
SPLIT SUBPARTITION "P_201802_SP_OTHERS"
VALUES ('US') INTO (SUBPARTITION "P_201802_SP_US", SUBPARTITION "P_201802_SP_OTHERS")
PARALLEL
/

Table INT_TMP altered.
```

etc.

You could generate the `split` statements from the data dictionary if you don't want to retype them all:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE INT_TMP SPLIT SUBPARTITION "' || subpartition_name || '"'
  || ' VALUES (''US'') INTO (SUBPARTITION "' || partition_name || '_SP_US",'
  || ' SUBPARTITION "' || subpartition_name || '");'
from user_tab_subpartitions
where subpartition_name = partition_name || '_SP_OTHERS';
```

and then run those generated statements. (Or do the same thing but run them automatically, using dynamic SQL in an anonymous block...)

Comment: How do i generate the split statements from the data dictionary if i dont want to retype ?

Comment: Where can be the value of the sub-partition template found?    What is the command to modify template from 20 to 16 sub-partitions when the names of sub-partitions are automatically generated.

Comment: why do i get ORA-14602: SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE is legal only for a composite partitioned table ?

Comment: I don't know. Please ask a new question with a [mre].